# Help withJS Form Validation

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, forms

I'm working on a js form validation and so far I have this:

```
        // grab form field values
    var valid = '';
    var name = $('form #name').val();

    // perform error checking
    if (name = '' || name.length <= 2) {
        valid = '<p>Your name' + required +'</p>';
    }
```

How can I validate that the user has chosen one of the options from a dropdown that I have in my form?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('select.foo').val();
```

check this

http://api.jquery.com/val/

Answer (score 1):

```
if($('select.your-class-here').val() !== '') { //value select

} else { //nothing selected

}
```